# How to create an IAM policy to grant full admin access for a particular region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-iam

I need to grant full admin access (All the AWS resources, not just few resources) for a specific region.
Below is the IAM policy configured. Anyway accessing to some other resources, it gives errors.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "rds:*",
                "apigateway:*",
                "s3:*",
                "lambda:*",
                "dynamodb:*",
                "ec2:*",
                "cognito-idp:*",
                "sns:*",
                "sqs:*",
                "cloudwatch:*",
                "cloudfront:*",
                "cloudformation:*",
                "ses:*",
                "codepipeline:*",
                "codebuild:*",
                "logs:*",
                "iam:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestedRegion": "ap-northeast-1"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include the errors that you are seeing along with your question, else it's hard to help you.

With a cursory glance though I see you are including iam:* to the statement that has the region condition. IAM is a global resource so on the surface I could see why that policy wouldn't work (can't try it myself). I would break that into a separate statement without the region condition, but then they have admin access to your entire IAM (security scary!).

If you want to provide a restricted admin, I would start by cutting back some of those permissions to the actions they actually require (* vs CreateGroup). Then delegating with namespacing like the example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_controlling.html) `"arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-ID-WITHOUT-HYPHENS:policy/TEAM-A/*"`. You can combine this with attribute tag conditions. [Demonstrated here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/simplify-granting-access-to-your-aws-resources-by-using-tags-on-aws-iam-users-and-roles/). This would allow them to move pretty freely but only in certain contexts. That being said, restricting those contexts can become quite complicated for you, the super-admin.

There may be other things to consider:

1. Do they really need IAM admin? How - in the way - would creating policies for them be in practice?
2. Could some of this pain be resolved by giving a separate account under and organization umbrella? Organizations can help enforce some of these policies [like regional restrictions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_aws-enable-disable-regions.html), budget maximums, but give a lot of control to the admins of those account.

Comment: What if you try also to use AWS Organizations - https://aws.amazon.com/organizations/ , for splitting access policy.

Comment: That's what I was trying to specify in number 2. I will try to make it more clear!